# Required argument [GenreSaveDTO dto] not specified

Tags: java, rest, microservices, micronaut

I'm currently learning micronaut in java and do an example in this [site](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-data-access-jpa-hibernate/guide/index.html). But everything seems doesn't work as I expected

Here is some code:

CrudRepository.java

```java
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    Optional<T> findById(@NotNull ID id);

    T save(@NotBlank String name);

    void deleteById(@NotNull Long id);

    List<T> findAll(@NotNull SortingAndOrderArguments args);

    int update(@NotNull ID id, @NotBlank String name);
}
```

GenreRepository (actually same as GenreRepositoryImpl like any others convention in spring webapp)

```java
public class GenreRepository implements CrudRepository<Genre, Long> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;  
    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    public GenreRepository(@CurrentSession EntityManager entityManager,
                               AppConfig appConfig) { 
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true) 
    public Optional<Genre> findById(@NotNull Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(Genre.class, id));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional 
    public Genre save(@NotBlank String name) {
        Genre genre = new Genre(name);
        entityManager.persist(genre);
        return genre;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(@NotNull Long id) {
        findById(id).ifPresent(genre -> entityManager.remove(genre));
    }

    private final static List<String> VALID_PROPERTY_NAMES = Arrays.asList("id", "name");

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Genre> findAll(@NotNull SortingAndOrderArguments args) {
        String qlString = "SELECT g FROM Genre as g";
        if (args.getOrder().isPresent() && args.getSort().isPresent() && VALID_PROPERTY_NAMES.contains(args.getSort().get())) {
                qlString += " ORDER BY g." + args.getSort().get() + " " + args.getOrder().get().toLowerCase();
        }
        TypedQuery<Genre> query = entityManager.createQuery(qlString, Genre.class);
        query.setMaxResults(args.getMax().orElseGet(appConfig::getMax));
        args.getOffset().ifPresent(query::setFirstResult);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public int update(@NotNull Long id, @NotBlank String name) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Genre g SET name = :name where id = :id")
                .setParameter("name", name)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

GenreSaveDTO.java

```java
public class GenreSaveDTO {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    public GenreSaveDTO() {}

    public GenreSaveDTO(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

GenreController.java

```java
@Validated
@Controller("/genres")
public class GenreController {

    protected final GenreRepository genreRepository;

    public GenreController(GenreRepository genreRepository) { 
        this.genreRepository = genreRepository;
    }

    @Get("/{id}") 
    public Genre show(Long id) {
        return genreRepository
                .findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(null); 
    }

    @Put("/") 
    public HttpResponse update(@Body @Valid GenreUpdateDTO dto) { 
        int numberOfEntitiesUpdated = genreRepository.update(dto.getId(), dto.getName());

        return HttpResponse
                .noContent()
                .header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, location(dto.getId()).getPath()); 
    }

    @Get(value = "/list{?args*}") 
    public List<Genre> list(@Valid SortingAndOrderArguments args) {
        return genreRepository.findAll(args);
    }

    @Post("/") 
    public HttpResponse<Genre> save(@Body @Valid GenreSaveDTO dto) {
        Genre genre = genreRepository.save(dto.getName());

        return HttpResponse
                .created(genre)
                .headers(headers -> headers.location(location(genre.getId())));
    }

    @Delete("/{id}") 
    public HttpResponse delete(Long id) {
        genreRepository.deleteById(id);
        return HttpResponse.noContent();
    }

    protected URI location(Long id) {
        return URI.create("/genres/" + id);
    }

    protected URI location(Genre genre) {
        return location(genre.getId());
    }
}
```

When I run the server and test api by using curl like:

```
curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8080/genres" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
     -d $'{
  "name": "music"
}'
```

But the console logged this kind of error:

```
21:10:42.112 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] ERROR i.m.h.s.n.c.UnsatisfiedRouteHandler - POST /genres (Bad Request): Required argument [GenreSaveDTO dto] not specified
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Annotate the post method with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`